# SQL reverse LIKE

Tags: sql, linq, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table holding a list of countries. Say one of these countries is 'Macedonia'

What SQL query would return the 'Macedonia' record if a search is made for 'Republic of Macedonia'?

I believe that in linq it would be something like

```
var countryToSearch = "Republic of Macedonia";

var result =  from c in Countries
              where countryToSearch.Contains(c.cName) 
              select c;
```

Now what would the SQL equivalent for the query above be?

Had it been the other way round (i.e. the database has the long version of the country name stored) the below query should work:

```
Select * from country
where country.Name LIKE (*Macedonia*)
```

but I do not see how I can reverse it.

Side note: the country names in the table will always be the short version of country names

Comment: She wants something like this:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f657d/11

Comment: Macedonia is no longer a country lol

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`CHARINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) for this.

```
Select * from country
where CHARINDEX(country.Name, 'Republic of Macedonia') > 0
```

Answer (score 14):

Just reverse the operator (and fix the syntax)

```
Select * from country
where 'Republic of Macedonia' LIKE CONCAT('%',country.Name,'%')
```

Comment: +1 : Who downvoted this? *(It should specify MySQL, as the op hadn't specified which RDBMS, but it surely works!  AND can be adapted to SQL Server...)*

Comment: I wrote the answer, before it was clear, that it is MSSQL - maybe people are unforgiving for the MySQL-ism.

Comment: I'm sure many other MySQL user will land here, just like me. And this is very helpful, while the accepted answer seems not to work for me and there are no questions like this about MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

For SQLite, a `substring` **(mysubstring column)** in a table **(mytable)** can be compared against an arbitrary larger test string:

`select * from mytable where instr('Somewhere substring is here', mytable.mySubstring) > 0`